# DataGridCheckBox initialize to all checked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm using .Net 3.5 with WPF and XAML.
I have a datagrid with the first column being a DataGridCheckBoxColumn.
This is inside of a window popup.
In the constructor, I sometimes want to initialize all rows to be selected, and other cases no rows to be selected.

Using data binding, I can initialize the checkbox on a row to either checked or not checked.
But I can't get the header checkbox checked along with all the checks on the rows in the case when all rows are to be checked.  How can I get to the checkbox?

```
<toolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn  CellStyle="{StaticResource SingleClickEditing}"  Visibility="{Binding exists}" Binding="{Binding Path=toTransfer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False">
    <toolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</toolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

I'm doing something like:

```
public MyPopupWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        if(checkMode.Equals("all"))
        {
            // Check all the items
            foreach (var item in bindList)
            {
                item.toTransfer = true;
            }
            // How to check the header checkbox?
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this but you can do

```
<CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked" Loaded="CheckBox_Loaded"/>
```

and

```
void CheckBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
        if(checkMode.Equals("all"))
        {
             checkBox.IsChecked = true;
        } 
    }
```